# JQuery in JS function doesn't work on the first click, but works after doing something else with that element.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to JQuery and Javascript, and after searching for an answer to my problem I am having a difficult time resolving it. I have a Javascript function openNav that is working perfectly to open and close a sidebar that I have built on my webpage, but I have a line of JQuery inside of the function that doesn't seem to work initially.

The goal of the code is to have a glyphicon change when the menu is opened and closed, and it works fine when clicking on the glyphicon itself. There are about 12 additional "menu" buttons that will also open the side bar. The sidebar opens just fine when clicking any of these buttons, however I cannot get the glyphicon to change on the initial click.

```
function openNav() {
    var sideNavBarElement = document.getElementById("sideNavBar");

    if (sideNavBarElement.style.width == "0px")
        $('#menutoggle').find('span').toggleClass('glyphicon-menu-right').toggleClass('glyphicon-menu-left');

    sideNavBarElement.style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main-body").style.marginLeft = "285px";
}
```

I have added this function into the code for each of my menu buttons, and after the menu is opened the first time the glyphicon will alternate using this code, but the very first time it is clicked it does not change. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: When you debug, which specific statement here doesn't produce the exected result?  Is your `if` condition true or false?  Does `$('#menutoggle')` match an element?  Does `$('#menutoggle').find('span')` find anything?  etc.

Comment: Is your `if` statement only supposed to run the one line which follows it? Right now the line starting ` $('#menutoggle').find('span')` depends on the `if` statement, but the next two lines `sideNavBarElement.style.width = "250px";` and `document.getElementById("main-body").style.marginLeft = "285px";` are run everytime, regardless of the result of the `if` statement

Comment: `$('#menutoggle')` does match an element, and it will find a span with the class `glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right`. And yes, the one line is supposed to be within the `if`.

Comment: @Katieev96: Is that not the line of code which is failing, then?  Which specific operation *is* failing?  There are many operations taking place in the code shown, narrow it down.

Comment: I believe I misunderstood your question. The line within the `if` statement, the one containing `$('#menutoggle')`, is the line that is failing to work when the button is initially clicked. After the sidebar has been opened the first time, the entire function works perfectly.

Comment: @Katieev96: Okay, but that line is doing a variety of operations all chained together.  Which one is failing?  You claim that when you debugged it successfully found the specific `span`(s) you wanted.  What classes were present on the matched element(s) at the time?  When each individual `toggleClass()` operation is invoked on the matched element(s), what happens?  It's highly unlikely that the `toggleClass` function itself "doesn't work" and more likely that you have a mistaken assumption in your logic.  Debug to narrow it down.