# Debugging a line of JQuery in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I am currently working on a project that includes a line of JQuery in a Javascript function. This line seems to be failing at some point, and I have been told to debug the line to see where it is failing. How do I do this in IE? I have tried to open developer tools and find a way to debug, and have not been successful. After clicking a few buttons on the page this line seems to work. I need to find out why it doesn't work on the initial click. Additional information: this line is nested in an `if` statement.

My line that doesn't work is:

```
$('#menutoggle').find('span').toggleClass('glyphicon menu-right').toggleClass('glyphicon-menu-left');
```

Comment: You need to provide more context into your question.  If it doesn't work fine the first time, and works fine later, then there is some dynamic nature of the elements it is trying to change and you need to show us the logic around that.  Also test in Chrome and Firefox to verify that this is, or is not, an internet explorer issue only (I'm going to guess that it is not).

Comment: I have posted the entire function in a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53208688/jquery-in-js-function-doesnt-work-on-the-first-click-but-works-after-doing-som I am simply asking how to debug with this question, not how to fix this specific line. Thank you.

Comment: If your question is "how to debug" then that's too broad of a question.

Comment: Is there no way to look and see which elements of this line are working properly and which are not using some kind of debugging tool in IE?

Comment: You can always throw in a `debugger;` statement to look at things, or use `console.log()` to log stuff to inspect them